# Create a list from a .txt file separating paragraphs

Tags: python

My current code is:

```
file = open("quotes.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
quote = 0

quoteList = [line.split()for line in open ("quotes.txt")]
print(quoteList)

lines = []
for l in lines:
  lines.append(l.split(" "))
```

I am trying to open a file and have it read the paragraphs in it and split them up into individual items in a list. It is a file filled with quotes and they all go something like this:

```
No problem should ever have to be solved twice.
-- Eric S. Raymond, How to become a hacker
```

There's about a thousand lines of quotes in the file and I am wondering how to split them up and put them into a list where you can access individual quotes and print them at random.

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: You need to show us your expected output. The quotes are on the same line, or subsequent lines? And in the output do you want the attribution line e.g. `-- Eric S. Raymond, How to become a hacker` to be included with the quote, or stripped from it, or what?